# System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I keep getting the following error message when I compile my code:

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

What could be causing it - this is my code so far:

Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

Form1.cs

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DriverNo")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the event from the GUI designer events, you get this:

Form1.Designer.cs:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

and in form:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The above is different from what you have. I am not sure whether you coded the code in your question by hand or what.

For CellClick, the code should be:

Form1.Designer.cs:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

and the in the form:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```